# Tools to write Integration tests with rspec 1, rails 2.3, ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-2, webrat

I've an application running with this setup:

- Ruby 1.8.7
- Rails 2.3.18
- Rspec 1.3.0

I want to write some integration tests and wanted to use `capybara`, unfortunally as far as I've researched it is not compatible with that setup. The latest `capybara` version compatible with `rails 2` is `1.1.4` but it requires `rubyzip` that requires `ruby 1.9`. I tried installing `rubyzip 0.9.9` that is compatible with `ruby 1.8`, but seems like that version of capybara is not compatible with it. So I dont know if it worth to try with an even older capybara version, or if is better to use other tool like `webrat`.

What alternatives do I have to write integration tests on this setup? What would be your choice?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise going for Cucumber and Webrat, IIRC that was what I used at that point in time.

Comment: cucumber does not the same that webrat? How I can install cucumber on that setup? I already tried everything with no-luck.